# plsql code to parse JSON without using third party libraries

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

JSON needs to be parsed using only PL/SQL code like regular expressions to get `sentiment` and `confidence` values out of it.

Something similar to [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29100262/Oracle-PLSQL-How-to-parse-JSON-response-without-using-any-3rd-party-library-packages-using-PLSQL-code-Database-is-Oracle-11g.html)

```
[
   {
      "sentiment":"negative",
      "confidence":0.6211975044276729
   },
   {
      "sentiment":"neutral",
      "confidence":0.3510681601407111
   },
   {
      "sentiment":"positive",
      "confidence":0.027734335431616075
   }
]
```

above JSON needs to be parsed to get `sentiment` and `confidence` values out of it

Comment: What's wrong with using Oracle's built in JSON functions?

Comment: What's your Oracle database version?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Built in JSON functions are available from 12.2 version, hence we cannot make use of those.

Comment: Oracle added some JSON support in 12.1.0.2.0. It's only for querying JSON but that seems to be all you need. Have a pipe at [the New Features Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12102.htm#NEWFT505).

Answer (score 3):

The [JSON_TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973) function is available starting with Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2).

```
SET NUMWIDTH 20 --Use this if SQL*Plus/ SQL developer truncates digits.

--test data
WITH t ( json_col ) AS ( SELECT '[
   {
      "sentiment":"negative",
      "confidence":0.6211975044276729
   },
   {
      "sentiment":"neutral",
      "confidence":0.3510681601407111
   },
   {
      "sentiment":"positive",
      "confidence":0.027734335431616075
   }
]'
  FROM dual
) --test data ends
SELECT j.*
FROM t
CROSS JOIN
     JSON_TABLE ( json_col,'$[*]'
          COLUMNS (
               sentiment  VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.sentiment',
               confidence NUMBER       PATH '$.confidence'
          )
     )
j;


SENTIMENT                      CONFIDENCE
-------------------- --------------------
negative                .6211975044276729
neutral                 .3510681601407111
positive              .027734335431616075
```

Comment: There are 2 approaches which I have concluded to use. 1. using JSON_TABLE 2. regular expressions.  Any ways, thanks Kaushik. I got the desired output. Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use any of the built-in JSON functions and your input does not involve any nested objects then you can use SQL with a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( json ) AS
SELECT '[
   {
      "sentiment":"negative",
      "confidence":0.6211975044276729
   },
   {
      "confidence":0.3510681601407111,
      "sentiment":"neutral"
   },
   {
      "sentiment":"positive",
      "confidence":0.027734335431616075
   }
]' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```
WITH rsqfc ( json, obj, lvl, cnt ) AS (
  SELECT json,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( json, '\{(.*?)\}', 1, 1, 'n' ),
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT( json, '\{(.*?)\}', 1, 'n' )
  FROM   test_data
  WHERE  REGEXP_COUNT( json, '\{(.*?)\}', 1, 'n' ) > 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT json,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( json, '\{(.*?)\}', 1, LVL + 1, 'n' ),
         lvl + 1,
         cnt
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  lvl < cnt
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( obj, '"sentiment":\s*"(negative|neutral|positive)"', 1, 1, 'n', 1 ) AS sentiment,
       TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( obj, '"confidence":\s*(\d+(\.\d*)?)', 1, 1, 'n', 1 ) ) AS confidence
FROM   rsqfc
```

**Output**:

```
SENTIMENT |          CONFIDENCE
:-------- | ------------------:
negative  |   .6211975044276729
neutral   |   .3510681601407111
positive  | .027734335431616075
```

**PL/SQL**:

Or using PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  json CLOB := '[
   {
      "sentiment":"negative",
      "confidence":0.6211975044276729
   },
   {
      "confidence":0.3510681601407111,
      "sentiment":"neutral"
   },
   {
      "sentiment":"positive",
      "confidence":0.027734335431616075
   }
]';
  cnt PLS_INTEGER;
  obj VARCHAR2(4000);
  sentiment VARCHAR2(20);
  confidence NUMBER;
BEGIN
  cnt := REGEXP_COUNT( json, '\{(.*?)\}', 1, 'n' );
  FOR i IN 1 .. cnt LOOP
    obj        := REGEXP_SUBSTR( json, '\{(.*?)\}', 1, i, 'n' );
    sentiment  := REGEXP_SUBSTR( obj, '"sentiment":\s*"(negative|neutral|positive)"', 1, 1, 'n', 1 );
    confidence := TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( obj, '"confidence":\s*(\d+(\.\d*)?)', 1, 1, 'n', 1 ) );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( sentiment || ' - ' || confidence );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
dbms_output:
negative - .6211975044276729
neutral - .3510681601407111
positive - .027734335431616075
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4019f47a772c51397cf4aa4743a544e4)*